# Атрибуты класса

Tags: python, ооп

Например, есть искусственный класс:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Как на самом деле мы получаем доступ к атрибуту? Когда мы обращаемся к атрибуту `x`, атрибут `x` инкапсулируется и мы на самом деле вызываем метод `x`, который возвращает этот самый атрибут?

```
some_class = SomeClass(3, 4)
print(some_class.x)
```

*Вопрос не про **private**, а про то, как реализован доступ к атрибуту.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого объекта (а в питоне абсолютно всё является объектом) есть специальный словарь, в который попадают все его аттрибуты в тот момент, когда вы их создаёте.

Посмотреть этот словарь можно так: `some_class.__dict__`

Каждый раз, когда интерпретатор видит `some_class.x` он пытается вызвать `some_class.__dict__['x']` и если такой ключ в этом словаре присутствует, то возвращет соответствующее значение. Если в словаре самого объекта нет ключа 'x', то интерпретатор будет пробовать найти его в словаре класса, к которому относится данный объект. Если и в словаре класса нет - то интерпретатор будет обращаться к предкам этого класса, а при необходимости - и к их предкам, и так вверх по цепочке до тех пор, пока либо не будет найден такой ключ, либо не будет достигнута вершина цепочки - object, от которого унаследовано всё. И только в этом случае интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку, что нет такого аттрибута.

Comment: Добавляем: `some_class.y = 10` и `print(some_class.y)` никаких ошибок об отсутствующем атрибуте нет :) Добавьте, тогда что это относится к get-атрибутам :)

Answer (score 1):

https://habrahabr.ru/post/137415/

Чтобы получить значение атрибута `attrname` экземпляра a в python:

1. Если определён метод `a.___class__.__getattribute__()`, то
   вызывается он и возвращается полученное значение.
2. Если attrname это специальный (определённый python-ом) атрибут,
   такой как `__class__` или `__doc__`, возвращается его значение.
3. Проверяется `a.__class__.__dict__` на наличие записи с `attrname`.
   Если она существует и значением является дескриптор данных,
   возвращается результат вызова метода `__get__()` дескриптора. Также
   проверяются все базовые классы.
4. Если в `a.__dict__` существует запись с именем `attrname`,
   возвращается значение этой записи. Если `a` — это класс, то атрибут
   ищется и среди его базовых классов и, если там или в `__dict__` a
   дескриптор данных — возвращается результат `__get__()` дескриптора.
5. Проверяется `a.__class__.__dict__`, если в нём существует запись с
   `attrname` и это “дескриптор не данных”, возвращается результат
   `__get__()` дескриптора, если запись существует и там не дескриптор,
   возвращается значение записи. Также обыскиваются базовые классы.
6. Если существует метод `a.__class__.__getattr__()`, он вызывается и
   возвращается его результат. Если такого метода нет — выкидывается
   `AttributeError`.

еще есть `__slots__` вариант доступа к атрибутам

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        '''доступ через "точка" - self.x'''
        return super().__getattribute__('__dict__')[item] + 1

print(SomeClass(x=1).x)
>>> 2
```

Comment: Спасибо за статью. Почитаю на досуге